# How can I get this script to error exit based on result of for loop?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a bash script which uses `set -o errexit` so that on error the entire script exits at the point of failure.
The script runs a `curl` command which sometimes fails to retrieve the intended file - however when this occurs the script doesn't error exit.

I have added a `for` loop to

1. pause for a few seconds then retry the `curl` command
2. use `false` at the bottom of the for loop to define a default non-zero exit status - if the curl command succeeds - the loop breaks and the exit status of the last command should be zero.

```
#! /bin/bash

set -o errexit

# ...

for (( i=1; i<5; i++ ))
do
    echo "attempt number: "$i
    curl -LSso ~/.vim/autoload/pathogen.vim https://tpo.pe/pathogen.vim
    if [ -f ~/.vim/autoload/pathogen.vim ]
    then
        echo "file has been retrieved by curl, so breaking now..."
        break;
    fi

    echo "curl'ed file doesn't yet exist, so now will wait 5 seconds and retry"
    sleep 5
    # exit with non-zero status so main script will errexit
    false

done

# rest of script .....
```

The problem is when the `curl` command fails, the loop retries the command five times - if all attempts are unsuccessful the for loop finishes and the main script resumes - instead of triggering the `errexit`.
How can I get the entire script to exit if this `curl` statement fails?

Comment: I can't reproduce what you describe. I copy-pasted your code, commented out the `curl` line and ran it. Output: `$ bash scratch.sh\n
attempt number: 1\n
curl'ed file doesn't yet exist, so now will wait 5 seconds and retry\n
✘-1`. It behaves exactly as it should: the `false` breaks the loop and the script exits with error code `1`.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Replace:

```
done
```

with:

```
done || exit 1
```

This will cause the code to exit if the `for` loop exits with a non-zero exit code.

As a point of trivia, the `1` in `exit 1` is not needed.  A plain `exit` command would exit with the exit status of the last executed command which would be `false` (code=1) if the download fails.  If the download succeeds, the exit code of the loop is the exit code of the `echo` command.  `echo` normally exits with code=0, signally success. In that case, the `||` does not trigger and the `exit` command is not executed.

Lastly, note that `set -o errexit` can be full of surprises.  For a discussion of its pros and cons, see [Greg's FAQ #105](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105).

#### Documentation

From `man bash`:

> **for** (( expr1 ; expr2 ; expr3 )) ; **do** list ;
>   **done**
>  First, the arithmetic expression expr1 is evaluated
>   according  the rules described below under ARITHMETIC EVALUATION.  The
>   arithmetic expression expr2 is then evaluated repeatedly until it
>   evaluates to zero.  Each time expr2 evaluates to a non-zero value,
>   list is executed and the arithmetic expression expr3 is evaluated.  If
>   any    expression  is  omitted,  it behaves as if it evaluates to 1. 
>   **The return value is the exit status of the last command in list
>   that is executed, or false if any of the     expressions is
>   invalid.** [Emphasis added]

Comment: Do you think it would be a good idea to put `true` before the break statement to be explicit and ensure the exit value of the loop?

Comment: I think that _explicit is better than implicit_.  That is why I wrote `exit 1` when just plain `exit` would have worked.  It is, though, a question of style and others can have their own opinions.

Comment: works nicely! thanks :) personally I would read `exit` as a plain exit - that terminates the script in its own right. `exit 1`  would read to me as a "signal" to some other process (i.e. `errexit`) - that it should terminate the script based on the "result" of `exit 1`. - so I have gone with `exit` but thanks for explanation

Comment: If your script is exiting because of an error condition, you _should_ call `exit 1`.  That does not affect `errexit` at all.  It merely tells the calling program that something went wrong.  The `false` command contains one statement: `exit(1)`.  99.9% of Unix commands return 0 on success and non-zero on error.  Your's should too.

Answer (score 14):

If you prefer to stop the loop on the first failure, and also to avoid `set -e`, you can do something like this:

```
for i in `seq 1 10`; do
  run_command || exit 1;
done
```

Comment: The `exit 1` does stop the loop, but it also stops the entire script. Replace it with `break` to stop just the loop (as you've described it)

Answer (score 2):

If you have `errexit` set, then the `false` statement should cause the script to exit immediately.  Same thing if the `curl` command failed.

You're example script, as written, should exit after the first `curl` command failure the first time it calls `false` if errexit is set.

To see how it works (I use the shorthand `-e` for to set `errexit`:

```
$ ( set -e;  false; echo still here )
$

$ ( set +e;  false; echo still here )
still here
$
```

So if the `curl` command executes more than once, this script doesn't have `errexit` set.

Comment: `set -e` is more subtle than that. It will _not_ exit after the first failed command in a loop.  You can prove that to yourself by running `(set -e; for (( i=1; i<5; i++ )); do echo $i; false; done || echo "FAIL"; )` and noting that the code runs `false` four times.  For more on `set -e`, see [Greg's FAQ #105](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105).

Comment: @John1024 Thanks.  This one's going down down down and out.

Comment: @John1024 But I guess the evidence is still that `errexit` wasn't set. Please apply the logic to the script in the question.  Run this: `(set -e; for (( i=1; i<5; i++ )); do echo $i; false; done ; echo still here )`   Yes testing return values with `if` `while` `||` `&&` etc does not trigger errexit.  The original script did not `||` the for loop.

Comment: I just noticed I hadn't shown the `set -o errexit` command in my example code, have added it now - and for me it was not error exiting as expected. I needed to keep the `false` as the last command in the for loop, then close loop with `done || exit [1]` - then it worked nicely!

Comment: @RobertL I see your point.

Comment: _if_ you turn on `errexit` and you don't put the `|| exit 1` after the loop, then the loop will exit after one iteration even if `break` is not hit.

Answer (score 1):

`set -o errexit` can be tricky in loops and subshells, because you have to pass the way back out of the process.

Breaking a loop (even in normal operation) is considered bad practice. You can call me old-school to prefer a while-loop rather than a for-loop for two conditions, but I find it better to read:

```
i=1
RET=-1
while [ $i -le 5 ] && [ $RET -ne 0 ]; do
    [ $i -eq 1 ] || sleep 5
    echo "attempt number: "$i
    curl -LSso ~/.vim/autoload/pathogen.vim https://tpo.pe/pathogen.vim
    RET=$?
    i=$((i+1))
done
exit $RET
```

Answer (score 1):

If `errexit` is set and the `curl` command fails the script terminates right after the failed curl command. In the bash manual there is no hint that `set -e` ignores any failed return status of a single in a compound command. This would be only the case if the compound command is executed in a context where `set -e` is ignored.
https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#The-Set-Builtin

Try a slightly adapted example posted by RobertL. This stops at the first for-iteration right after the false command:

```
( set -e; for (( i=1; i<5; i++ )); do echo $i; false; echo "${i}. iteration done"; done ; echo "loop done" )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add the --fail option to the curl command, this will solve your problem, the script will fail and exit on error if the curl command fails, if very useful too when using curl in jenkins pipeline :

```
curl -LSso --fail ~/.vim/autoload/pathogen.vim https://tpo.pe/pathogen.vim
```